# Calculate voltage using KCL

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits

[image]

Find $v_0$
My attemp:I try to find out the v1 first.
KCL at node v1: $\frac{v_1}{5}+\frac{v_1-3}{1}+\frac{v1-4v_0}{5}=0$
Then,by voltage divider rule $v_0=\frac{2}{6}V_1$ . I get the wrong answer and  I don't know where i am wrong.

Comment: One error: 2+3=5, not 6.

Comment: yes,why does it not include the 1 ohm resistor in the left loop?@ThePhoton

Comment: Because that resistor is not part of the divider.

Comment: Assuming you're calling the bottom node the ground node, like your equations imply.

Comment: You could do it  by superposition ...